# Does SO have a plan for dead users?

Tags: discussion, users

SO is awesome. I suspect it will be around for a while.
Is there a plan for handling dead users (as in actually not alive anymore)?

I was just thinking about this after looking at a 'User was removed'.

It seems that in ~30 years or so, there may be many SO users that have passed.

Would their account be deleted, or locked with perhaps a RIP?

Comment: Why would anything need to be done? Plenty of people have stopped using SO altogether and their content is still around...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126733/user-inactivity-due-to-well-death-profile-info-age-keeps-adding-years

Comment: Thx Cody, my search for 'dead users' did not seem to find those.

Comment: Considering SO users are mostly humans, and every living things will pass away due to aging by nature, I suggests we should differentiate "deceased", "deleted by owner's request" and "deleted by forced removal" users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There really doesn't need to be.  Users [that aren't with us anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300/aaronsw) for [whatever reason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) aren't to be distinguished beyond users who are inactive.

Also, without any form of actual authentication on accounts, it'd be tough to demarcate a user as "deceased" or "no longer active here".

You also describe the "User was removed" notice - that's something [entirely different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed), and nothing special besides their account being *completely* nuked for moderation purposes needs to take place.